# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleImputer'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```
all_data = pd.concat([train_data, test_data])
average = all_data.Age.median()
print('Average Age: {0}'.format(average))
train_data.fillna(value= {'Age' : average, inplace : True})
test_data.fillna(value= {'Age' : average, inplace : True})
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-42-e465cf5beb42> in <module>()
       1 all_data = pd.concat([train_data, test_data])
 ----> 2 average = all_data.Age.median().values()
       3 print('Average Age: {0}'.format(average))
       4 train_data.fillna(value= {'Age' : average, inplace : True})
       5 test_data.fillna(value= {'Age' : average, inplace : True})
 
 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py
 in nanmedian(values, axis, skipna, mask)
     611     if not is_float_dtype(values.dtype):
     612         try:
 --> 613             values = values.astype("f8")
     614         except ValueError as err:
     615             # e.g. "could not convert string to float: 'a'"
 
 TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
'SimpleImputer'
```

Hi, I'm stuck with this case, this is shown the same even when using scikit-learn. Please help me out and thanks in advance!!

Comment: all_data.Age.median() should be a scalar, I would get rid of .values() to the right of it. Also, make sure the age column has only numbers on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
median = all_data['Age'].median()
train_data['Age'] = train_data['Age'].fillna(value=median)
test_data['Age'] = test_data['Age'].fillna(value=median)
```